# Markdown editor bug for inline code links

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks, editor

I think there is a bug with the editor.

1. Create a inline codeblock with the back ticks.
   `SomeClassName`
2. Double click the single word which highlights SomeClassName.
3. Click add a link and save it. `[SomeClassName][1]`
4. Notice how it is rendered. It puts the link code inside the back ticks.

I feel that the add a link should be smart enough to wrap the back ticks in this case.
I generally like to link to MSDN stuff like this. See my answer here: [How to create my custom helper in asp.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405564/how-to-create-my-custom-helper-in-asp-net-mvc/5405598#5405598)

Comment: Sorry, I responded explaining how to create a code link manualy, but I have checked that using the mouse and the "add link" button, and have found the buggy behaviour reported by @Daniel exactly as he says (+1).

Comment: "I feel that the add a link should be smart enough to wrap the back ticks in this case" -- so how would you handle the case when you selected on part of the code block?

Comment: I'm not sure. Could it be if i select the whole back ticked block?